# Show images relevant to each other vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, dom, stylesheet

I have some `SVG` images and have to form a map through them.
I have done custom styling through CSS padding and margin (individually) but the formation doesn't last when check on different screens.
I also tried by making parent div `float` and set child properties as `top` and `left` but this also results in overlap on different screens.
[image: ling]

The Snapshot is attached. 
kindly suggest any work-around or library to solve this issue.

Comment: use absolute and relative positioning

Comment: @CodeBoyCode already using absolute and relative positioning but alignment changes on different screens

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you statically positioned the images since you used padding and margin to move them where you wanted them to go. By doing this, you are only positioning these elements for the size of the current viewport. By default, CSS positions are set to static, so the images will move with the flow of the page as you resize. To fix this, you can set the CSS of the images to be "position: absolute".

Here's a link to W3 schools explanation of CSS positioning: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use Media queries to make adjustments for different screen sizes https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

A good framework with media queries built in is bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

This might be overkill if all you need is media queries but without it you are going to need to write a lot of CSS rules.

Knowing more about your project and what you are already using might yield better suggestions.